# Generic Node.js $INIT_CWD for Windows and *nix

Tags: node.js

How can I replace `$INIT_CWD` in a Node.js run script with something "generic" that also works on Windows?

**package.json in root**

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    ...
    "scripts": {
        ..
        "start": "live-server $INIT_CWD/foobar --port=8080"
    }
}
```

**Test**

This works fine on Linux and macOS; serves files from `test/foobar`.

```
$ cd test
$ npm start
```

However, on Windows it would have to be `%INIT_CWD%` instead of `$INIT_CWD`.

How can I modify `package.json` to be OS-agnostic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The/one solution is to use `cross-env-shell` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env.

> Run scripts that set and use environment variables across platforms

```
"devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env-shell live-server $INIT_CWD/foobar --port=8080"
}
```